# Logarithmic Spiral Calculus Question

Tags: calculus, plane-curves

I am working on this problem. Even some of the notation has me confused (the vectors $\vec i$ and $\vec j$).

> Let $\vec r(t):=ae^{-bt}\cos(t)\vec i +ae^{-bt}\sin(t)\vec j$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive constants. The trace of $\vec r (t)$ is called the logarithmic spiral.
>
> (a) Show that as $t \to +\infty $, $\vec r (t)$ approaches the origin.
>
> (b) Show that $\vec r (t)$ has finite arc length on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: $\vec i$ and $\vec j$ are common notation for orthogonal vectors. In a more modern notation, you would say that the spiral is a function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $$f(t)=\left(a e^{-bt}\cos(t),a e^{-bt}\sin(t)\right)$$

Comment: Recall that the arclength of the parametric curve $x=f(t)$, $y=g(t)$ as $t$ goes from $p$ to $q$ is $\int_p^q\sqrt{(f'(t))^2+(g'(t))^2}dt$.  Compute the derivatives carefully, square them, add. There will be magic simplification.

Comment: Sorry, I should have provided more. Is using the vector notation an alternative to $y=ae^{-bt}cos(t), x=ae^{}$?

Comment: For part (a), I will be calculating the limit of each $x=f(t)$ and $y=g(t)$ as they approach infinity?

Comment: @J.Borges: Usually $i$ is the unit vector along the $x$-axis, so in the question two above, you have reversed $x$ and $y$.  No big deal, but might as well get it right. For question above, yes, you calculate the limits, which are clearly $0$, since the $e^{-bt}$ term goes to $0$, and the sine and cosine always have absolute value $\le 1$. And it is not as "they" $\to\infty$, it is as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: I've got it down to $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sqrt{b^{2}a^{2}e^{-2bt}cos^{2}(t)+a^{2}e^{-2bt}sin^{2}(t)+b^{2}a^{2}e^{-2bt}sin^{2}(t)+a^{2}e^{-2bt}cos^{2}(t)}dt$ but now I am at a bit of a loss. I am trying to get rid of the square root.

Comment: Get rid of the $\cos^2$'s and (+) $\sin^2$'s! You are close..

Answer (score 1):

The length is given, as the OP wrote, by
$$\int_0^\infty\sqrt{a^2b^2e^{-2bt}(\cos^2t+\sin^2t)+a^2e^{-2bt}(\cos^2t+\sin^2t)}\,\,dt=$$
$$=\int_0^\infty ae^{-bt}\sqrt{b^2+1}\,\,dt=\left.-\frac{a\sqrt{b^2+1}}{b}\,e^{-bt}\right|_0^\infty=\frac{a}{b}\sqrt{b^2+1}$$